# How to combine multiple classifications data, into one image chart using Google Earth Engine, for the purpose of visualization?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

I am trying to create a LULC map of my study area for the period of 2018-2021. I have classified the regions in 4 classes, and would like to plot the classified area for each class and for each year on one map.

Something like this
[image]

Currently, I am only able to plot them separately, like this,

[image]

How can I combine them?

Here is my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/651540ad45d987f4c10004b6c83a2ce2)